# xcode firebase message error OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic3

I have an application in ionic 3 (legacy) when building it I get the error in the Firebase Messaging library in this part of the file "GtalkExtensions.pbobjc"

```
if (!OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier(nil, worker, (void * volatile *)&descriptor)) {
      [worker release];
    }
```

> Conflicting types for 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier'

Declaration of 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' must be imported from module 'Darwin.libkern.OSAtomic' before it is required

Implicit declaration of function 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' is invalid in C99

How to solve this problem I already removed cocoapods completely and tested several versions and it didn't help.

Mac Mini M1
Mac OS Ventura
XCode 14.2

Comment: Same issue, happened out of nowhere and now I can't compile

Comment: I m facing same issue and not able to solve it.

Answer (score 18):

The problem is related to new Protobuf (3.23.X) library. If you want to fix your current version of Firebase without upgrading to the latest one you can pin a previous working version of 'Protobuf' in your Podfile:

```
...
target 'YourTarget' do
  project 'YourProject'
  ...
  pod 'Protobuf', '= 3.22.1' # Pinned version for Firebase Messaging
end
```

Then remove Podfile.lock and run `pod install`.

Comment: Thanks, resolve for me using pod 'Protobuf', '= 3.22.1'

Answer (score 5):

it's might be incompatible with Protobuf.
maybe you can try to specific another version in Podfile.lock like

```
- Protobuf (3.21.12)
```

Comment: Nice catch, looks like Protobuf was last updated a week or two ago, which correlates with whenever this issue start popping up.
Trying deploying the fix to our CI, but it appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I have find smth like
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier.3.html

it is **very bad idea**, but actually it works

You can import at in files with this error and continue work

```
#include <libkern/OSAtomic.h>
```

Comment: Hi @nifsss. This appears to have solved our problem of running the app, but, if I may ask, why is it a very bad idea.. and can/should we go to PROD with this code in there??

Comment: @RiaanP Hi! i just found this solution for comfortable work, and ofcourse u can can go to PROD with this, by u should think about - this is a 3rd library, u already dependent from this code, u know nothing about this core, and trying change smth inside. It's can crush mb, in vary bad cases, i dont wanna test it, and probably u too)

 i updated cocoapods yesterday and problems have dissapeared

Comment: I added it in files GtalkCore.pbobjc.m and GtalkExtensions.pbobjc.m and it works

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded everything firebase related to the latest version and the error is gone.
Example:

```js
"@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links": "^7.5.1",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.5.0",
"@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^17.5.0",
```