# firebase message error OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier in xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, swift

I have podfile having firebasemessaging in it. suddenly this error start coming and I can't compile my code in xcode 14.2.

Conflicting types for 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier'

Declaration of 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' must be imported from module 'Darwin.libkern.OSAtomic' before it is required

Implicit declaration of function 'OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier' is invalid in C99

My Mac M1 has OS 13.3.1 (a)
My cocopods version is 1.12.1.

It's native swift language application. I have seen one question same like mine with "ionic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230814/xcode-firebase-message-error-osatomiccompareandswapptrbarrier)"