# XCode 14.3.1 FirebaseMessaging GTalkExtentions.pbobjc error

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, xcode14.3

I am trying to run a legacy code that is working fine with other people & same system configurations but not on my Mac M1 13.5 and xcode 14.3.1
[image]

**- Call to undeclared functions

- Declaration must be imported from Module
- Conflicting types**

Solutions that I tried-

1. Delete xcworkspace, PODS folder & lock file, Derived Data, restarting
2. pod deintegrate
3. pod install
4. pod --repo-update
5. Run Destinations with Rosetta

   FirebaseMessaging is the main culprit here

Sample PodFile

```
platform :ios, '11.0' 

project 'MyProj’, 'ReleaseAppStore' => :release

inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyTrarget do

    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVision'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionTextModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionAutoML'
end


target ‘MyApp’ do

    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVision'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionTextModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionAutoML'
end

target ‘MyAppRest’ do
    
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVision'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionTextModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionAutoML'
 
end


post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0' # update target to project target

            if config.name == 'Debug' # update compilation mode to match main project build settings
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'] = 'singlefile'
            else
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'] = 'wholemodule'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: tried with different deployment targets like 12.0 and 13.0 but none worked

Answer (score 0):

Credit to the answer the helped me
[xcode firebase message error OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtrBarrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230814/xcode-firebase-message-error-osatomiccompareandswapptrbarrier)

My updated POD file-

```
platform :ios, '11.0' 

project 'MyProj’, 'ReleaseAppStore' => :release

inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyTrarget do

    pod 'Protobuf', '= 3.22.1'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVision'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionTextModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionAutoML'
end


target ‘MyApp’ do

    pod 'Protobuf', '= 3.22.1'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVision'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionTextModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionAutoML'
end

target ‘MyAppRest’ do
    
    pod 'Protobuf', '= 3.22.1'
    pod 'FirebaseCore'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
    pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVision'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionBarcodeModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionTextModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionFaceModel'
    pod 'FirebaseMLVisionAutoML'
 
end


post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0' # update target to project target

            if config.name == 'Debug' # update compilation mode to match main project build settings
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'] = 'singlefile'
            else
                config.build_settings['SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE'] = 'wholemodule'
            end
        end
    end
end
```